# VBA how to create variable name containing variable

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a macro with a variable number of players (1 and up). These players should be Player1, Player2, etc. How can I create variable names "on the fly"?

The best I can think of is something like this:
    a=a+1
    Dim Player&(a)

Comment: Any reason for not using an array? (`Dim player(1 To 10) As String: player(1) = "test1", player(2) = "test2"`,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Dictionary instead (treat keys as variable names): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234